# Ensure regex test fails even if string matches an earlier portion of the pattern

Tags: javascript, regex

Apologies if the title is too vague, I don't know the terminology for this issue so any suggestions would be much appreciated!

Current pattern: `^(?:\/[^\/]*){2}(?:\/tree|)`

Target language/platform: JS

Inputs and expected results:

```
1. /foo/bar                                 pass
2. /foo/bar/tree/baz                        pass
3. /foo/bar/tree/baz/foobar                 pass

4. /foo/bar/blob                            fail
5. /foo/bar/blob/x.js                       fail
```

Testing mechanism: `pattern.test(entryString);`

These are GitHub paths, and what I'm trying to do is match a repository (`/foo/bar`), or any subpath (`/foo/bar/tree/baz/....`). The third path segment should be `tree` if it exists, else, the test should fail.

The problem with the pattern above is that the 4th & 5th items still pass despite matching neither condition of that pattern. It's probably some silly mistake, but can't figure out what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could optionally match `/tree` followed by optional repetitions or `/` and other chars than `/` and assert the end of the string `$` to prevent partial matches.

```
^(?:\/[^\/]*){2}(?:\/tree(?:\/[^\/]*)*)?$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:\/[^\/]*){2}` Repeat 2 times `/` and optionally any char except `/`
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\/tree` Match `/tree`
  - `(?:\/[^\/]*)*` Optionally repeat `/` any char except `/`
- `)?` Close the non capture group and make it optional
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/UsaVLh/1)

If you don't need to match the whole string, you can assert the end of the string in the alternation:

```
^(?:\/[^\/\n]*){2}(?:\/tree\/|$)
```

Comment: ++ but `^(?:\/[^\/\n]*){2}(?:\/tree\/|$)` might be bit shorter

Comment: @anubhava Yeah you got a point there :-)

Comment: Ah, that's the regex I was envisioning (though couldn't form). Thanks to you both!